# joomla install from folder option giving errors

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have an extension to install to upload into the joomla 3.4.5 and it is greater than 2Mb and getting this figured raised is not likely.

So I want to use the 'install from folder option'

Its the extension_name zip

Here's what I have done:

Unzipped it into a folder called extension_name

Uploaded this folder into the tmp folder for the site

Set the path field into the 'install from folder' to /path_to_temp_folder/extension_name

When I press install I get this error:

> "Please enter a package folder. Unable to find install package"

I look in the folder event_registration_pro_v3.2.5 and I see this:
backend - folder
frontend - folder
changelog.txt
install.name.php
name.xml

I really need a fast answer with this so any ideas!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to put the whole content of you extension_name.zip into your tmp folder under your joomla Installation.
So unzip the extension and copy it via ftp to /tmp.
At *Extensions: Install* go to *Install from Folder* and press the *Install* Button.

On newer version you can try to change the folder in *Install from Folder* the correct subfolder [joomla root path]/tmp/[your sub folder]

Comment: I donot understand the above said. Kindly provide me the step by step guide. It will be useful for me then